# Carrier Sense Multiple Access with Collision Detection and Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, telecommunication, ieee, data-link-layer

I had a doubt,  CSMA/CD is used by Ethernet. Ethernet is end to end, ie connected between two nodes. I hope, It has different channel for transmission and reception. Then how  could a collision occur. Can't understand,   correct me if I am wrong. Tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSMA/CD is rarely used these days, and was completely removed with the removal of the half-duplex option in gigabit ethernet spec.  Even if there are separate TX and RX lines, the hub could be full-duplex in which case CSMA/CD is in play.  To understand CSMA/CD, think of a room full of people:  before talking you first listen to see if anyone else (the MA=Multiple Access part) is already talking (the CS=Carrier Sense part), then after you talk you listen for interruptions (the CD=Collision Detection part).  ([a single] Ethernet is not always completely end-to-end, BTW)

Comment: Thank you very much for sparing time for answering the question. Your answer/explanation is correct. In full Duplex its no-longer CSMA/CD , these are independent channels. I found this link useful. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ethernet-the-definitive/1565926609/ch04.html . Also when I mentioned end-to-end its only node-to-node not endpoint-to-endpoint. Thanks for your effort sir

Comment: I am glad to help; please check the answer as excepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, ethernet ran on coax, and still does. Transmission and reception both happened on a single wire. And on that cable you could have many systems all trying to send traffic at once. Search for 10base2, 10base5.